# Enumerator printing out strings from a language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

Write down the algorithm of an enumerator that prints
out EXACTLY ONCE every string in the language L = {7m+ 2 |

m ∈
N} over the alphabet A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}.

In regards, to the enumerator, it prints out L when L accepts. How is the alphabet connected to the language, is it the input into the language? or is it the output from the language?

Comment: I find the question confusing, since there is no reference to $A$ in the language. Are you sure that it is $m \in N$ and not $m \in A$?

Comment: Yes that's the full question word for word

Comment: does  L ⊂ A* help?

Comment: You comment @Sue answers you question (if I understand the question). The relation between the language and the alphabet is $L\subseteq A^*$. Here, the alphabet is all the digits (0 to 9). Therefore, $A^* = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Okay so in regards to answering the question, do you have any tips for approaching it? This is the first time I have attempted  this type of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the algorithm asks you to list out every number of the form $L = \{7m + 2 ~\vert~ m \in \mathbb N\}$.

Note that since we should just print each number once, let's check if by iterating over the different values of $m$, if we can get the same number.

\begin{align*}
7a + 2 = 7b + 2  \\
7 (a - b) = 0 \\
a = b
\end{align*}

That is, if $(7a + 2 = 7b + 2)$, then $(a = b)$.  So, we can literally *enumerate* all numbers and be guaranteed that we won't repeat values.

If you know how to read python, the algorithm would be:

```
def listL():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(7 * i  + 2)
        i += 1
```

Comment: great explanation, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean + 2 instead of + 1 also?

Comment: Yep, I just fixed that :)